# Trace of the product af oa positive definite matrix and a negative semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices. Let us assume $A$ to be a positive difinite and $B$ negative semidefinite. 
Is it true that 
$$
\text{trace}(AB) \le 0 \quad \text{?}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: $AB$ is similar to $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ which is symmetric negative definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $-B$ is positive (semi)definite. Compute ${\rm trace}(A(-B))$.